# Codeigniter extending native email library

Tags: codeigniter

I want to add custom headers when sending an email with codeigniter.

I've created the file `MY_Email.php` and put in `application/libraries` with the below code:

```
class MY_Email extends CI_Email {

      public function __construct(array $config = array())
  {
    parent::__construct($config);
  }


    public function set_header($header, $value){
        $this->_headers[$header] = $value;
    }
}
```

Now when i try to use `$this->email->set_header('Message-Id', $new_message_id."@example.co.uk");` I can't send any emails i get this error
**Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Email::set_header()**

How do i solve?

Comment: Are you loading your library or the core library?

Comment: I'm loading the core library

Comment: CI_Email::set_header() means you are not calling MY_Email , try check it out.